# Convert java enum to scala Enumeration for json4s serialization

Tags: java, scala, json4s

I'm using the [json4s](https://github.com/json4s/json4s) library to convert scala case classes into json messages.  My case classes are dependent on third party java enum types:

```
//third party java code
public enum Fruit {
    Banana (1),
    Cherry (2);
}
```

My scala classes then use this enum as a parameter:

```
case class Order(fruit : Fruit, quantity : Int)
```

I'm trying to [use `EnumNameSerializer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442618/serialize-and-deserialize-scala-enumerations-or-case-objects-using-json4s) provided by the `org.json4s.ext' library:

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.Serialization
import org.json4s.native.Serialization.{write, read}
import org.json4s.ext.EnumNameSerializer

case class Order(fruit : Fruit, quantity : Int) {
  implicit lazy val formats =
    DefaultFormats + new EnumNameSerializer(fruit)
}
```

But, I'm getting a compile time error:

> error: inferred type arguments [Fruit] do not conform to class
>   EnumNameSerializer's type parameter bounds [E <: Enumeration]

**How do I convert a java enum into a scala Enumeration for json4s' EnumNameSerializer?**

I'm hoping to avoid writing a [custom serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190886/writing-custom-serializer-for-json4s) since my actual use case involves many different java enum types used in my case class and therefore I would have to write many different custom serializers.

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: why not write a custom serializer for your enum? You write it only once

Comment: @TrustNoOne As I wrote in the question, these are 3rd party enums and there are many of them.

Comment: Oh sorry, you wrote "many different enum values" and I thought you had just one enum with many values

Comment: @TrustNoOne I updated the confusing section you mentioned.  Thanks.

Comment: You can use Enum.valueOf(class, name) to create a generic serializer, have a look at my answer ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?

```
class EnumSerializer[E <: Enum[E]](implicit ct: Manifest[E]) extends CustomSerializer[E](format ⇒ ({
  case JString(name) ⇒ Enum.valueOf(ct.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[E]], name)
}, {
  case dt: E ⇒ JString(dt.name())
}))



// first enum I could find
case class X(a: String, enum: java.time.format.FormatStyle)
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats + new EnumSerializer[java.time.format.FormatStyle]()

// {"a":"test","enum":"FULL"}
val jsonString = Serialization.write(X("test", FormatStyle.FULL))
Serialization.read[X](jsonString)
```

Answer (score 3):

This functionality is out-of-the-box now, you can use it like this:

```
implicit val formats: Formats =
  DefaultFormats + new JavaEnumNameSerializer[Fruit]()
```

It was merged there following @Giovanni-s answer and my PR to the library.