# Generically Serialize Java Enums to json using json4s

Tags: scala, serialization, enums, json4s

Our finatra application uses json4s to serialize objects to jsons in our controller responses. However, I noticed that when trying to serialize enums, it creates an empty object.

I saw this response that would resolve my issue but would have to be replicated for each enum:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35850126/2668545

```
class EnumSerializer[E <: Enum[E]](implicit ct: Manifest[E]) extends CustomSerializer[E](format ⇒ ({
  case JString(name) ⇒ Enum.valueOf(ct.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[E]], name)
}, {
  case dt: E ⇒ JString(dt.name())
}))

// first enum I could find
case class X(a: String, enum: java.time.format.FormatStyle)
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats + new EnumSerializer[java.time.format.FormatStyle]()

// {"a":"test","enum":"FULL"}
val jsonString = Serialization.write(X("test", FormatStyle.FULL))
Serialization.read[X](jsonString)
```

Is there a way to make a generic custom serializer that would handle all java enum instances by grabbing their .name() value when serializing to json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a clean solution because of the type-safety constraints. Still if you are OK with a hacky solution that relies on the fact that Java uses type erasure, here is one that seems to work:

```scala
class EnumSerializer() extends Serializer[Enum[_]] {
  override def deserialize(implicit format: Formats): PartialFunction[(TypeInfo, JValue), Enum[_]] = {
    // using Json4sFakeEnum is a huge HACK here but it seems to  work
    case (TypeInfo(clazz, _), JString(name)) if classOf[Enum[_]].isAssignableFrom(clazz) => Enum.valueOf[Json4sFakeEnum](clazz.asInstanceOf[Class[Json4sFakeEnum]], name)
  }

  override def serialize(implicit format: Formats): PartialFunction[Any, JValue] = {
    case v: Enum[_] => JString(v.name())
  }
}
```

where `Json4sFakeEnum` is really a fake `enum` defined in Java (actually any `enum` should work but I prefer to make it explicitly fake)

```java
enum Json4sFakeEnum {
}
```

With such definition an example similar to yours

```scala
// first enum I could find
case class X(a: String, enum: java.time.format.FormatStyle)

def js(): Unit = {
  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats + new EnumSerializer()

  val jsonString = Serialization.write(X("test", FormatStyle.FULL))
  println(s"jsonString '$jsonString'")
  val r = Serialization.read[X](jsonString)
  println(s"res ${r.getClass} '$r'")
}
```

Produces following output:

> jsonString '{"a":"test","enum":"FULL"}'
>   
>  res class so.Main$X 'X(test,FULL)'

---

**Update or How does it work and why you need `Json4sFakeEnum`?**

There are 2 important things:

1. Extending [`Serializer`](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/7da6a8458246dadb46fa7fff930823d6bf590d19/core/src/main/scala/org/json4s/Formats.scala#L201-L204) instead of [`CustomSerializer`](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/7da6a8458246dadb46fa7fff930823d6bf590d19/core/src/main/scala/org/json4s/Formats.scala#L404-L416). This is important because it allows creating a single non-generic instance that can handle all `Enum` types. This works because the function created by `Serializer.deserialize` receives `TypeInfo` as an argument so it can analyze runtime class.
2. `Json4sFakeEnum` hack. From the high-level point of view it is enough to have just a `Class` of the given enum to get all names because they are stored in the `Class` object. However on the implementation details level the simplest way to access that is to use [`Enum.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)) method that has following signature:

```java
public static <T extends Enum<T>> T valueOf(Class<T> enumType, String name)
```

The unlucky part here is that it has a generic signature and there is a restriction `T extends Enum<T>`. It means that even though we have proper `Class` object the best type we know is still `Enum[_]` and that doesn't fit the self-referencing restriction of `extends Enum<T>`. On the other hand Java uses type erasure so `valueOf` is actually compiled to something like

```
public static Enum<?> valueOf(Class<Enum<?>> enumType, String name)
```

It means that if we just trick the compiler into allowing us to call `valueOf`, at the runtime everything will be alright. And this is where `Json4sFakeEnum` comes on the scene: we just need some known at the compile time specific subclass of `Enum` to make the `valueOf` call.

Comment: Hey @SergGr - Thanks, that's pretty cool that you were able to get it to work. I'm still having quite some difficulty interpreting what is going on though. How is `FormatStyle` able to work with the `Json4sFakeEnum`? In the end, I'll probably go with the more verbose but legible option but just how you did this interests me.

Comment: @ThinkBonobo, I tried to clarify this in the Update. Please let me know if this is stil unclear.